# Can't fill in the Hidden text area element

Tags: python, selenium, iframe, robotframework, selenium2library

F1, need some help or hints with **Hidden element** using Robotframework.
The problem consist that to fill any text in the text area, I need to change the state of text area from `display:none;` `to display:block;`

[Needed text area for input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAXdh.png)

[Code that I see from WebDev Tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQaCE.png)

The code itself:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="cazary" style="width: 664px;">
    <div class="cazary-commands-wrapper">
        <ul class="cazary-commands-list">
            <li unselectable="on" title="Size" class="cazary-command-fontsize">Size</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="cazary-commands-list">
            <li unselectable="on" title="Foreground Color" class="cazary-command-forecolor">Foreground Color</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="cazary-commands-list">
            <li unselectable="on" title="Background Color" class="cazary-command-backcolor">Background Color</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="cazary-commands-list">
            <li unselectable="on" title="Remove Format" class="cazary-command-removeformat">Remove Format</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <iframe class="cazary-edit" src="javascript:" style="height: 39px;"></iframe>
    <textarea id="summernote" class="required-preview field cazary-source" placeholder="Tell us all about your Advertisement. This description will be prominently displayed in your Advertisement notice. Feel free to adjust the fonts and background colour too." name="observations" cols="50" rows="10" style="display: none;"></textarea>
</div>
```

My Robotframework code tries:

```
Select Frame      //iframe[@class="cazary-edit"]
# First try
Input text      //textarea[@id="summernote"]    ${UniversalVariableforName}
# Second try
Input text      //iframe[@class="cazary-edit"]    ${UniversalVariableforName}
# Third try
Input text      //div[@class="cazary"]//iframe[@class="cazary-edit"]    ${UniversalVariableforName}
# Fourth try
Input text      //body[@class="empty"]    ${UniversalVariableforName}
# Fifth try
Input text      //iframe[@class="cazary-edit"]//body[@class="empty"]    ${UniversalVariableforName}
```

Errors that were returned:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wrc0y.jpg)

May be there is a solution with *Execute Javascript* keyword?

Comment: text area is out side of iframe and also, it is hidden. you cann't interact with it.

Comment: are you able to enter value manually?

Comment: Hi @Murthi, Yes, I'm able to fill manually any info in the specified text area

Comment: Please don't post pictures of the errors. Take the time to properly copy, paste, and format them into your question.

Comment: If you're able to fill it in manually, most probably there is another element that is actually taking the input, and then propagates the value to the textarea by JS. Find the other one, and target it - by manipulating the display of the textarea your test will not replicate real user interaction.

Comment: Like @Todor I don't see the value of this DOM editing approach. How will it add to the overall confidence that the application under test is behaving as expected? As the end user wouldn't be doing what you're doing, I'd recommend finding the right user behaviour and mimic that.

Answer (score 1):

The concerned `<textarea>` is outside of the `<iframe class="cazary-edit">`. Hence we don't need to switch to the `<iframe>`

To send the text to the **`Input`** field you can try to :

- Use `xpath` as :

  ```
  "//textarea[@class='required-preview field cazary-source' and @id='summernote']"
  ```
- Click the `Input` field first.
- Next Clear the `Input` field.
- Finally try to send the text.

---

### Update :

As the concerned `textarea` have the `style` attribute set as **`"display: none;"`**, we have to change to **`"display: block;"`** through `JavascriptExecutor` then send the text.

---

### Python Sample Code :

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('ID').style.display='block';")
```

Comment: Hi @DebanjanB , I have tried you solution, unfortunately it didn't help. <br> But I observed that needed element is hidden, so I googled for a while and found ideas to change the state of a DOM element, in my case in the `textarea` , should change `style="display: none;"` to `display:block;` <br> Tried that idea too, but nothings cganges, returned a fail.