# How to select a list item from the dropdown list using Xpath for Robot framework Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework, ant-design-pro

I want to select `Textes3` with robot framework from the dropdown.

HTML:

```
<div class="ant-select-dropdown ant-select-dropdown--single ant-select-dropdown-placement-bottomLeft" style="width: 389px; left: 342px; top: 969px; display: none;">
<div id="eryerye12ry56756rt" tabindex="-1" class="ant-select-dropdown-content" style="overflow: auto; transform: translateZ(0px);">
<ul role="listbox" tabindex="0" class="ant-select-dropdown-menu ant-select-dropdown-menu-vertical ant-select-dropdown-menu-root">
<li role="option" class="ant-select-dropdown-menu-item ant-select-dropdown-menu-item-active" unselectable="on" brnalid="ethduyuyuyujfyeroT" style="user-select: none;"> Texte1 </li>
<li role="option" class="ant-select-dropdown-menu-item" unselectable="on" brnalid="ksdhfiyzegyufizyefge" style="user-select: none;"> Texte2 </li>
<li role="option" class="ant-select-dropdown-menu-item" unselectable="on" brnalid="zrzeonvisyjrddudgfi56" style="user-select: none;"> Texte3 </li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is element which you want to select always 3rd `li` of `ul`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to select the text "Textes3" from the above you can use the below xpath

```
//li[contains(text(),'Textes3')].click();
```

If this does not answer your question, so please explain it more.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to select any of the dropdown item as the parent *`<div>`* contains the *`style`* attribute value as [***display: none;***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47832218/7429447).

You need to look at some other elements to perform this specific operation.