# ElementNotInteractableException error identifying a Select element using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, drop-down-menu, html-select, display

I learn Selenium in Java and I'm struggling with little problem.
I'm working on handling dropdowns and to resolve my probelm I have to use Select class.
I wrote a selector:

```
@FindBy(css="#speed")
WebElement selectSpeed;
```

Then I wrote a method :

```
public SelectMenuPage selectRandomSpeed(){
getWaitForTheElement().untilElementIsPresentCss("#speed");
      //webDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(locator)));
        Select select = new Select(selectSpeed);
        select.selectByIndex(0);
        return this;
    }
```

The problem is that when I use Select class the code simply does not work and I receive:

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable: 
Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated
```

It works very well when, instead of using Select, I just put the selectors of all the wanted elements and just simply interact with them. Unfortunately, I **have to** use Select class.

Here is my DOM
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As per the HTML, the [html-select](/questions/tagged/html-select) tag is having the *`style`* attribute set as [***display: none;***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47832218/7429447).

[image: display_none]

Unless the element is ***visible*** within the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) **`Select()`** may not work properly.