# Selenium: Can't access an input element using Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, input, display

Code trials:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver

PATH = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://oncf-voyages.ma")

origin = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/section/div[1]/div[2]/main/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/input')

origin.send_keys("something")
origin.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

I used the python code above to try and practice some basic operations with selenium but I can't access an input clause
Here's the website that I'm working on : https://www.oncf-voyages.ma/
This is a part of the html code of the website:

```
<div class="ant-col SearchForm_col ant-col-xs-24 ant-col-md-24 ant-col-xl-24 ant-col-xxl-24" style="padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px;"><label class="SearchForm_label">Ma gare de départ</label><div class="InputWrapper"><div id="origin" class="SelectPicker SelectWidget ant-select ant-select-enabled"><div class="ant-select-selection
    ant-select-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true" aria-controls="b5b887d5-0fcf-488c-dc1a-9dca53b48787" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0"><div class="ant-select-selection__rendered"><div unselectable="on" class="ant-select-selection__placeholder" style="display: block; user-select: none;">Ma gare de départ</div><div class="ant-select-search ant-select-search--inline" style="display: none;"><div class="ant-select-search__field__wrap"><input id="origin" autocomplete="off" class="ant-select-search__field" value=""><span class="ant-select-search__field__mirror">&nbsp;</span></div></div></div><span class="ant-select-arrow" unselectable="on" style="user-select: none;"><i aria-label="icon: down" class="anticon anticon-down ant-select-arrow-icon"><svg viewBox="64 64 896 896" focusable="false" class="" data-icon="down" width="1em" height="1em" fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true"><path d="M884 256h-75c-5.1 0-9.9 2.5-12.9 6.6L512 654.2 227.9 262.6c-3-4.1-7.8-6.6-12.9-6.6h-75c-6.5 0-10.3 7.4-6.5 12.7l352.6 486.1c12.8 17.6 39 17.6 51.7 0l352.6-486.1c3.9-5.3.1-12.7-6.4-12.7z"></path></svg></i></span></div></div></div></div>
```

Comment: it's a little odd that the input has no "type" attribute.... but try with XPATH of //input[@id='origin']

Answer (score 0):

The *`<input>`* with you are trying to locate with the [*xpath*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50882166/7429447):

```
/html/body/div[1]/section/div[1]/div[2]/main/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/input
```

is within it's **ancestor** *`<div>`* with ***style*** attribute set as [***`display: none;`***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47832218/7429447)

[image: oncf-voyages-ma]

So Selenium won't be able to interact with the element unless it's ***visible***, ***enabled*** and ***interactable(clickable)***.

Comment: hey thanks for your feedback, i'm still a beginner with selenium so can you give me a solution for that problem ? or is it even possible to do that or not ?

Comment: @EVOLVE Ofcoarse that's possible but you have to raise a new question as per your new requirement.